# How to get unique URL identifier after inserting item in Google Base with Zend Gdata API?

Tags: zend-framework, google-base

I need to get the unique URL identifier for the product that is created after inserting an item into Google Base using the Zend_Gdata_Gbase library.

I can't seem to do this.  I am finding a startling lack of documentation online about manipulating the objects used in these applications.

The url that I add to the object does not work to retrieve the base item later, which is why I need to get the one that google generates upon submission.

I am writing a program that will need to be able to delete content at a later date, and thus will need to store that information in order to keep the website synced with the Google Base feed.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is... after having created the new entry, you run the code to insert the entry.

```
$dryRun = false;
$createdEntry = $service->insertGbaseItem($newEntry, $dryRun);

$http = $createdEntry->service->getHttpClient();
$headers = $http->getLastResponse()->getHeaders();
return $headers['Location'];
```

This gives you the unique URL that is different from the URL you can insert as a link.  If you aren't inserting your own links, you can access the unique url much more easily:

```
return $createdEntry->link[0]->href;
```

I hope this helps somebody else.